# Using file input field field on modal to update hidden field on main view

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, modal-dialog

I have a HTML page with a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="imageInput1T1" name="imageInput1T1" />
```

Within this main page I also have a modal window that is shown up click of a button:

```
<div id="templateModal1" class="reveal-modal friend-modal">
  ...............................
</div>
```

I have a browse field within my modal, how can I use the selection of a file in this field to populate the imageInput1 field on my main page so that I can post it through a form submit? If I select the file in the modal using the input and then post files then my Request.Files is empty. I have a hidden field on the form field how can i send the file chosen in the modal input to the hidden field?

Answer (score 0):

--- EDITED -----

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var fileInput = $("#yourInputFileId").on('change', function () {
                $("#imageInput1T1").val = $(this).val();
            });
        });
```

--- EDITED 2 ----

So the code is no teste but should work (do correct syntax if is the case):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var saveButton = $("#your-save-button-id");
        saveButton.on('click', function () {
            var form = $("#your-form-id"),
                yourFile = $("#your-file-field-id"),
                modelContentHidden = $("#modal-content-hidden-id-in-your-form"),
                modalContent = $("#templateModal1").htlm();

            modalContentHidden.val(modalContent);
            yourFile.remove();
            form.append(yourFile[0]);
            form.submit();
        });
    });
```

Comment: its a file im looking to capture in the hidden field, its on the smae page just displayed in a modal

Comment: you can listen the 'onchange' event of this input.file and then access the value. The value of the input.file will be the path or name of the selected file.

Comment: why do you want to post the value of the file field? What your trying to do only get you the file path/name and not the actual file, is it really that what you want?

Comment: I am trying to make a WYSIWYG email editor where the user can upload their images to pre-existing templates. Then when they do I want to post the file to cloud storage and save the string to a hidden field so that I can capture the HTML of the modal window which will be used for the email generation

Comment: So what you want is to get the user to choose an image, then show this image in the mail/template he's editing and when he is happy with the template he click in 'save' button and you upload the image and the template to store it in the cloud for later use by the user, something like that?

Comment: yup exactly that, I have the preview int he template showing etc just want to know how to save the selected file to my template in the form of a storage location rather than dataLimage jpeg:asdsajdiasjdigijhasdighid etc

Comment: An so far your image is being showed/previewed to the user, or you'r not there yet?

Comment: I have this done no problems, just need to work out how to post the file save the location update the image sources of the images and then save the html page of the modal window

Comment: Ok, to upload the file you have to set  the _enctype_ property in your form to "multipart/form-data" so `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and in the save event from your modal you can get the file field and put it in your form. I will edit the code to show an exemple, but that should work. The remaining operations have to be done in the server side.

Comment: I have the local file location saved in the hidden field, now I want to past the file from the location in the hidden field to my controller by using HttpPostedFileBase image1T1 = form.GetValues("imageInput1T1"); but this is not working as i cannot convert string[] to a postedfile

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC?
I don't think you can do that only by saving de location in a hidden field.
Check you have set the _enctype_ attribute in the form.
Do what I do in my exemple in the answer.
Add a property `HttpPostedFileBase  imageInput1T1` to your model, and MVC will manage the rest.